# Xubuntu - Logitech presenter works only partialy

Tags: wireless, xubuntu, logitech

I have 2 old Logitech presenters, older and newer. Both worked under Ubuntu 10.10. 
Now I have Xubuntu 14.04 and older presenter works good, but new only partialy (only PgUp/PgDown, not F5 and dot.)

It's `dmesg` from new:

```
[74315.083647] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[74315.181566] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52d
[74315.181573] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[74315.181577] usb 2-1.2: Product: USB Receiver
[74315.181581] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[74315.190416] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/input/input19
[74315.190685] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52D.0005: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[74315.196456] input: Logitech USB Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.1/input/input20
[74315.196929] hid-generic 0003:046D:C52D.0006: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input1
```

`dmesg` from old

```
[74368.724751] usb 2-1.2: new low-speed USB device number 8 using ehci-pci
[74368.823011] usb 2-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c515
[74368.823016] usb 2-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[74368.823020] usb 2-1.2: Product: USB Wireless Receiver
[74368.823023] usb 2-1.2: Manufacturer: Logitech
[74368.830815] input: Logitech USB Wireless Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.0/input/input21
[74368.831131] hid-generic 0003:046D:C515.0007: input,hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Wireless Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input0
[74368.835919] input: Logitech USB Wireless Receiver as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2:1.1/input/input22
[74368.836356] hid-generic 0003:046D:C515.0008: input,hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Wireless Receiver] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.2/input
```

Older MODEL NAME: R-R0001.
 
Newer model name: R400

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same issue with my Logitech R400. From what I could tell, this is supposed to be handled in the file `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb`. That file specifies button presses to catch and turns them into "standard" events like `presentation` and `displaytoggle`.  But this isn't working properly in 14.04.

The comments in the top of that file tell you how to override it.  So I followed the instructions and it worked!  Below are the instructions I followed.  I copied the section out and modified it to work like it does on Windows.  These bindings work on LibreOffice Impress that comes with 14.04 as well as evince in presentation mode.

1. Open your text editor.
2. Copy the following and paste into the editor.

   ```
   # Logitech Presenter R400
   keyboard:usb:v046DpC52Dd*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in00*
    KEYBOARD_KEY_070029=esc
    KEYBOARD_KEY_07003e=f5
    KEYBOARD_KEY_070037=b
   ```
3. Save the file as `70-keyboard.hwdb`.
4. Open a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
5. Change directory to where you saved the file, if necessary.
6. Copy the file to the appropriate place so that it overrides the bad entry and doesn't get clobbered by updates by running the following command.  Enter your password when prompted.

   ```
   sudo cp 70-keyboard.hwdb /etc/udev/hwdb.d
   ```
7. Do udev magic so that our changes are picked up.

   ```
   sudo udevadm hwdb --update
   sudo udevadm trigger /dev/input/event*
   ```
8. It doesn't say so in the file, but I had to reboot before the changes took.

One note that I found important.  Apparently, Windows doesn't use a single key to "toggle" into and out of presentation mode.  <kbd>F5</kbd> is used to begin the presentation and <kbd>ESC</kbd> is used to end the presentation.  To give the effect of toggling presentation mode on and off, the remote itself first sends <kbd>F5</kbd> then sends <kbd>ESC</kbd>.

So if the presentation has been started by you pressing <kbd>F5</kbd> at the keyboard, pressing the "presentation" button on the remote will do nothing at first button press.  It just sends <kbd>F5</kbd> again.  The second time you press the "presentation" button, it sends <kbd>ESC</kbd> and the presentation will end.