# Logitech R400 on Lenovo T440s, Ubuntu 14.04 not properly recognized

Tags: usb, lenovo, udev, logitech, input-devices

I would like to use a Logitech R400 pointer with my Lenovo T440s running on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit. There is a problem with the keys so that forward and backward buttons result in jumping at 1st or last slide respectively.

So I followed the instructions in this previous post ([Xubuntu - Logitech presenter works only partialy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/565555/xubuntu-logitech-presenter-works-only-partialy/576012#576012)) and tried to figure out the scancodes (http://derickrethans.nl/logitech-r400-take2.html).

- It didn't work as the device is not properly recognized. Instead of recieving something like:

  `lsusb`

  ```
  Bus 004 Device 003: ID 046d:c52d Logitech, Inc.
  ```

  I get:

  ```
  Bus 002 Device 017: ID 0e00:0111
  ```
- Instead of `/dev/input/by-id` containing

  ```
  usb-Logitech_USB_Receiver-event-kbd
  ```

  I have:

  ```
  usb-MOUSE_USB_MOUSE-event-kbd 
  usb-MOUSE_USB_MOUSE-event-if01-event-mouse
  usb-MOUSE_USB_MOUSE-event-if01-mouse
  ```

Accordingly, the device is not recognized as a R400 so that modification of `/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-keyboard.hwdb` or newly created `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboard.hwdb` have no effect.

Does anybody know why the R400 is not properly recognized and how to correct this?

Thank you for your time considering my issue!

**Update:**

According to `xinput`, the pointer device is:

`Virtual core pointer` -> `MOUSE USB MOUSE id=17`
`Virtual core keyboard` -> `MOUSE USB MOUSE id=11`

- Output of `./getscancodes /dev/input/event17`:

  ```
  Input driver version is 1.0.1
  Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0xe00 product 0x111 version 0x110
  Input device name: "MOUSE USB MOUSE" ^[OH^[OF^[^[[15;2~b
  ```
- Output of `./getscancodes /dev/input/event11`:

  ```
  Input driver version is 1.0.1
  Input device ID: bus 0x0 vendor 0x0 product 0x0 version 0x0
  Input device name: "HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8" ^[OH^[OF^[^[[15;2~b
  ```
- However, id=11 says in `xinput --list-props 11` that it is related to `/dev/input/event9`. scancodes of event9 are:

  ```
  Input driver version is 1.0.1
  Input device ID: bus 0x3 vendor 0xe00 product 0x111 version 0x110
  Input device name: "MOUSE USB MOUSE"
  458827 (0x7004b) ^[OH458827 (0x7004b) 458830 (0x7004e) ^[OF458830 (0x7004e) 458981 (0x700e5) 458814 (0x7003e) ^[[15;2~458981 (0x700e5) 458814 (0x7003e) 458757 (0x70005) b458757 (0x70005)
  ```

  These partially correspond to scancodes given link ([Tweaking the Logitech R400 presenter tool on Linux](http://derickrethans.nl/logitech-r400-take2.html))

**Update:**

Id is changing from time to time, so today the device is id=17.

Scan codes for this device are as follows:

left button -> `458827 (0x7004b)`

right button -> `458830 (0x7004e)`

start presentation -> `458793 (0x70029)`

blank screen -> `458793 (0x70029)`

Comment: See here how to get related event device file than scancodes  https://askubuntu.com/a/668030/26246 , then post outputs . `xinput` can list all input devices id

Comment: Got it! Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Good, no bp.  yes event number is not the same as xinput device id. Yes device with id=11 is what we are looking for  and those are the scan code we need. I don't have such device, could you post a map of scancode vs button name. Try them one by one . Then add it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create new hwdb file:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboard.hwdb
   ```
2. Put this in it:

   ```
   keyboard:usb:v0E00p0111d*dc*dsc*dp*ic*isc*ip*in00*
   KEYBOARD_KEY_070029=f5
   KEYBOARD_KEY_07004b=left
   KEYBOARD_KEY_07004e=right
   ```
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit.
4. Update udev database

   ```
   sudo udevadm hwdb --update
   ```
5. Reboot

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I know the Question is quiet old, but since im still using the presenter mentioned here I'll add my solution.
I had the same problem on Archlinux. It was working for me this way.

Create custom config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/udev/hwdb.d/70-keyboard.hwdb
```

Put this into the file and save (coorect device ID and my scancodes):

```
# R400
evdev:input:v0E00p0111*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_700e5=f5  # presentation button
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7003e=f5  # presentation button
 KEYBOARD_KEY_70005=f8  # monitor button
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7004b=left
 KEYBOARD_KEY_7004e=right
```

you might have to adjust the scancodes, since the start presentation scancode seems to differ from mine (and it should show two scancodes for the presentation button, you have to add them both).

run

```
sudo systemd-hwdb update
```

and

```
sudo udevadm trigger
```